# Custom page with no headers, footers and its own CSS, Javascript

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I want to create a custom page that uses custom css and custom javascript, what I want is to be able to add this custom html page to my posts, so I have everything ornanized. And I want this post to don't have any headers nor footers so It's blank, and I will add what I want, via html,css and javascript.

Comment: Do you need the page to have anything to do with Wordpress at all? For example, do you want it to contain information that you enter in the Wordpress dashboard for editing pages? It might be useful to add why you want to do this

Comment: I don't want any template from wordpress, I want to put my raw html + css + javascript. I want to this beacuse It's a text generator using GPT-2 (python neuronal network) So I want a posts like mywebsite.com/text-generator   and there put my html + css + js. And have wordpress to manage the urls and categories, so I have everything organized in the same place.

Comment: You can still use a WordPress template for that.  There's no rule that says you 'have to' include WP content in a WordPress template - you're just assigning a template to a page on your WP site (which you can leave entirely blank) and then when that page loads the template, your output is whatever you want it to be.  You don't have to use the header, the footer, or even the <head> tag from WordPress.

Comment: I don't quite understand the value you get from trying to put your content inside Wordpress, or Wordpress inside your content? It seems like it would be better to have a separate place to host your non-Wordpress stuff, and then link to it from Wordpress pages if you need to. Otherwise you're going to spend a lot of time cutting out all the stuff that Wordpress is useful for because you don't need it. More info on how you want to integrate the two things might lead to more useful suggestions

Comment: I just want wordpress to manage all the slug / urls / SEO stuff /ads, for these custom pages I am making.